# What's the best way to strip created_at and updated_at from an ActiveRecord instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to strip the created_at and updated_at fields from an instance before it's serialised and pushed to a client. What is the neatest way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: i initially thought `remove_timestamps(table_name)` was an answer for this, but it looks like you'll need something else. :\

Comment: JSON then passed to Juggernaut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ideas. Assuming for the examples that the model has name, email and timestamps.

When fetching the record do:

```
Model.find :select => [:name, :email]
```

i.e. not including the timestamps fields.

If you are serializing through JSON do:

```
model.to_json :only => [:name, :email]
```

or

```
model.to_json :except => [:created_at, :updated_at]
```